# How to change page numbering on chapter bages using scrbook and scrlayer-scrpage

Tags: latex

I am currently writing my thesis using scrbook and changed the footer layout. However, I also want to change the footer on Part and Chapter pages as well. What do I need to change for this? Currently, it basically looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4o9o.png) right now. I want to have the page number in the center of the Chapter/Part page as well.

Example code:

```
\documentclass[english, 12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[automark,ilines]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead{}
\ihead{\headmark}
\chead{}
\cfoot{-~\pagemark~-}
\ofoot{}
\ifoot{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an optional argument to set the styles for the plain pages:

```
\documentclass[english, 12pt]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[automark,ilines]{scrlayer-scrpage}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\ohead[]{}
\ihead[whatever]{\headmark}
\chead[]{}
\cfoot[something]{-~\pagemark~-}
\ofoot[]{}
\ifoot[]{}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Introduction}
\blindtext[5]
\end{document}
```